# Join pairs of elements of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
list_to_transform = [['Start', 'двигаться', 'конгресс', 'сша'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'в'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет', 'израильский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'на'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'и']]
```

What i need is to combine each two words into single string, and if single word is left, combine it with previous two:

```
result =[['Start двигаться', 'конгресс сша'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона в'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']]
```

Is there some elegant way to do so? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try list comprehension

Comment: `list` is a bad idea  for a variable name

Comment: Don't name lists `list`, it overrides the builtin `list`

Comment: @IvanVinogradov thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension with an `if` / `else` clause to decide your indexer.

```
res = [[' '.join(i[k:(k+2 if k+3 != len(i) else k+3)])
        for k in range(0, len(i)-1, 2)] for i in lst]

print(res)

[['Start двигаться', 'конгресс сша'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона в'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join adjacent words in a list of even length with `map('{} {}'.format, lst[::2], lst[1::2])`. The rest is handling the odd case and mapping over the lsit of lists.

```
lsts = [['Start', 'двигаться', 'конгресс', 'сша'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'в'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет', 'израильский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'на'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'и']]


def proc_single(lst):
    # join adjacent words
    res = list(map('{} {}'.format, lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
    # correct for lists with odd length
    if len(lst) % 2:
        res[-1] = '{} {}'.format(res[-1], lst[-1])

    return res

for lst in lsts:
    print(proc_single(lst))

# ['Start двигаться', 'конгресс сша']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона в']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский']
# ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']
```

Answer (score 1):

group the strings 2 by 2 in the inner list comprehension, use an outer list comprehension to iterate on the sublists.

Add a little trickery to join by 3 if reaches the end of the list so you don't have orphans. And make sure you're iterating up to an *even* range so the orphan isn't repeated (finetuned with trial and error :))

```
lst = [['Start', 'двигаться', 'конгресс', 'сша'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'в'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет', 'израильский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'на'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'и']]

result = [[" ".join(subl[i:i+(2 if i < len(subl)-3 else 3)]) for i in range(0,(len(subl)//2)*2,2)] for subl in lst]
```

result:

```
[['Start двигаться', 'конгресс сша'], ['Start двигаться', 'сторона в'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']]
```